# How to add JQuery Light Slider inside Light box Modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, lightbox

I'm using jQuery lightSlider as image slider. I want to have sliders inside Light box. Nevertheless, I have found the following situation: In the first Image the slider is OK. In the second Image the slider content is not Working.

**My (simplified) html:**

```
 <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="kt_modal_1{{ $example->id }}">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered  modal-xl mw-70%">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 p-5">
                            <a href="{{ $example }}" data-lightbox="photos"> 
                              <img class="img-fluid photo-gallery rounded mw-250px bg-
                               image hover-zoom" src="{{ $example }}">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

**lightbox CDNs**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.8.2/css/lightbox.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.8.2/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
```

**lightslider CDNs**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.6/css/lightslider.css" integrity="sha512-+1GzNJIJQ0SwHimHEEDQ0jbyQuglxEdmQmKsu8KI7QkMPAnyDrL9TAnVyLPEttcTxlnLVzaQgxv2FpLCLtli0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This light slider on modal problem is well-known. If this issue on github is still unresolved when you check, you might need to consider other options. You can use a lightbox, a magnifying popup, or an owl-carousel to accomplish the same functionality for that purpose.